# localstorage с множественным выбором и занесением данных в форму

Tags: javascript, jquery, localstorage

Вопрос такой.
Можно ли в `localstorage` вносить несколько значений, а затем, в нужный момент добавлять сохраненные данные в форму?
Или же, как лучше всего реализовать функцию понравившегося товара с отправкой формы?

Попробую разъяснить точнее. Есть разные страницы на которых находятся изделия. Причем это может быть список изделий или страница изделия. При нажатии на кнопку, изображение из изделия и его название отправляется в созданную скриптом панель.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделать все это я смогу, но, мне нужно, чтоб данная панель висела при перемещении по сайту именно с данными изделиями. Так же, выборочно убирать добавленные изделия с панели.

Похожий принцип есть в готовом виде [тут](https://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ProductComparison/).

Однако, там идет сравнение товаров и данные очищаются при обновлении страницы, а мне нужно именно аналог `"Список желаний"`. После нажатия на кнопку `"Order"` человек попадает на определенную страницу, например `site.com/order` где есть обычная почтовая форма. При открытии этой страницы и наличии данных в `localstorage` они сразу добавляются в поле формы. указав `ID`, название или другие данные.

Comment: Можно все что угодно: `JSON.stringify/JSON.parse`

Answer (score 3):

Создаёте массив:

`var selectedProducts = [];`

Затем добавляете в него нужный продукт:

`selectedProducts.push({id: 123, name: 'Продукт': image, '/img/img.jpg'});`

И сохраняете:

`localStorage.setItem('selectedProducts', JSON.stringify(selectedProducts));`

При открытии страницы получаете сохранённые продукты:

`var selectedProducts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedProducts') || '[]');`

Comment: Спасибо. А не могли бы минимально собранный пример накидать. Я так понимаю, что проще всего через `data-attribute` указать значения. Или разместить кнопку и из родительского контейнера извлечь `id`, `name` и `image` используя `.parent` и `.find`, а затем по клику отправлять в массив данные. Сохранение в `localStorage` на этот же клик вешается. А с извлечением и раскидыванием данных из массива совсем не справился.