# Разные события на кнопке в зависимости от расположения ее на определенной странице (JS)

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage, table

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста осилить проблему, я уже совсем запутался(
В `index.html` создаю таблицу, в ней строка, в строке в одной из ячеек кнопка Delete. Функцией `delButton` помещаю содержимое строки в localstorage, саму строку удаляю со страницы. Перехожу на `deleted.html`, функцией `deletedLS` уже загружена моя строка в точно такую же таблицу. Уже тут нажимаю удалить - строка удаляется, но одновременно с этим опять заносится в хранилище дополняя там существующий ключ и после перезагрузки страницы уже две таких одинаковых строки подтягивает((
Как сделать чтобы на `index.html` при удалении добавлялась строка в localstorage а уже в `deleted.html` ПРОСТО удалялась? Сделать 2 разных функции? Подцепить какое-то условие?? 3 дня мучаюсь не хватает мозгов, хелп!

```js
function insertRow(id) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById(id);
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.setAttribute('class', 'row_class');

  var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
  btnDelete.type = 'image';
  btnDelete.className = 'btndelete';
  btnDelete.setAttribute('id', 'btndelete_id');
  btnDelete.src = 'icons/delete.png';
  btnDelete.setAttribute('onclick', 'delButton(event)');

  var tdItem = document.createElement("td");
  tdItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));

  var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
  tdPrice.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));

  var tdAction = document.createElement("td");
  tdAction.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
  tdAction.className = 'td_action';
  tdAction.appendChild(btnEdit);
  tdAction.appendChild(btnDelete);

  row.appendChild(tdItem);
  row.appendChild(tdPrice);
  row.appendChild(tdAction);

  tbody.appendChild(row);

  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML);
  return false;

}

function delButton(elemCheck) {
  var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
  var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;

  var currentlist = localStorage.getItem('DeleteList');
  if (currentlist === null) {
    currentlist = '';
  }
  currentlist += elCheck.outerHTML;
  localStorage.setItem('DeleteList', currentlist);
  elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);
  localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
}

function deletedLS() {
  var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody'),
    DeleteList = localStorage.getItem('DeleteList');
  if (DeleteList !== null) {
    tbody.innerHTML = DeleteList;
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Cart - Done Items</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="icons/shortcut_done.ico" />
</head>

<body onload="doneLS();return false;" class="body">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="index.html">Shopping list</a></li>
      <li class="li_done"><a class="link_done" href="done.html">Done</a></li>
      <li class="li"><a class="link" href="deleted.html">Deleted</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <h1 class="h1">Done Items</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="mytable" id="myTable" cellspacing="0" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr id="tr_id" class="tr">
          <th class='td'>#</th>
          <th>Done</th>
          <th>Item</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price $</th>
          <th colspan="2" width="100">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody">


      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Начните с простого. На странице `deleted.html`:

```
<script>
  var skipDeleteToLocalStorage = true;
</script>
```

В функции:

```
function delButton(elemCheck) {
  var checkboxElement = elemCheck.target;
  var elCheck = checkboxElement.parentElement.parentElement;

  var currentlist = localStorage.getItem('DeleteList');
  if (currentlist === null) {
    currentlist = '';
  }
  currentlist += elCheck.outerHTML;
  elCheck.parentElement.removeChild(elCheck);

  if (window.skipDeleteToLocalStorage) {
    localStorage.removeItem('DeleteList');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('DeleteList', currentlist);
    localStorage.setItem('ShoppingList', document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо! Я о таком даже не знал... Это помогло избавиться от дополнительной записи в хранилище при нажатии на Delete из `deleted.html`. Теперь думаю как избавиться от той записи, которая была добавлена при удалении из `index.html`...

Comment: @TheHateInMe Вы на наличие этого флага можете прикрутить любую логику изменения данных в `localStorage`.

Comment: если вставить в условие вместо вашего комментария `localStorage.removeItem('DeleteList');` то будет работать до тех пор, пока там одна строка. Как только их будет несколько, хранилище очистится и после F5 таблица будет пуста. Я полагаю, надо применить тот же метод, что и в случае с `currentlist`?

Comment: @TheHateInMe Конечно. Эта логика будет настолько простой или сложной, насколько требуется по тех. заданию. Принцип Вы, по-видимому, уже уловили.

Comment: понял, сейчас попробую что-нибудь наваять

Comment: если честно, я не очень понимаю как мне это сделать... допустим,  у меня в хранилище две строки, я их получаю, записываю в переменную... далее - когда я кликаю Delete на одной из строк в таблице, я могу получить ее содержимое... теперь мне надо взять мою переменную, удалить из нее содержимое активной строки и положить новое значение в хранилище. В итоге там в хранилище должна остаться та строка, которую я не удалял. Соответственно, она единственная и загрузится при очередном F5.. Блин, на словах все понимаю, а как на код это уложить - хоть убейте(

Comment: @TheHateInMe Сейчас, я недавно видел вопрос про то, как работать со сложными данными в `localStorage`.

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763236 , и вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764544